# High Level language with Low level Graphics

Tags: graphics

I am looking for a high level language which will still allow me to work directly with graphics. I want to be able to modify screen pixels, for instance. But I do not want to write huge amounts of code for each operation. I want simple one line commands for graphics somewhat like those listed below. What are some programming languages which would have these features?

Possible pseudocode:

```
Screen.clear
Graphics.line(4,5,20,25).color=green
Circle(centerx,centery,radius)
```

Comment: Off-topic, SO doesn't do recommendations.  Try http://processing.org/

Comment: And you're calling this "low level"?!?

Comment: I looked at processing.org and it looks interesting. I will try it out and see if it is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do (ie, how complex do you need to get?) [Processing](http://processing.org/) is a *very* high-level, graphics-focused environment. Note, however, that it seems to be focused on the fixed function OpenGL pipeline, which is deprecated (though arguably the easiest and most intuitive way to get started).

Processing is built in Java, runs in web browser (or from your desktop), and abstracts most of the initialization and cleanup code required to use OpenGL.

**Edit** 
*I've just noticed your comment that says you're not an experienced programmer. In that case, I'd recommend starting with Processing. Once you get the hang of it, move on to Python.*

Another, slightly more complex, option is Python. Python is very powerful, fairly easy to pick up (depending upon your prior development experience), and widely supported. It'll also allow you to use shaders and other features from the 21st century, and is cross-platform [See this link for PyOpenGL](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/), the first Python OpenGL site that popped up in google.

Then, there's [C# + OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com/). This can get pretty complex pretty quickly, but is very powerful, and since it's compiled (under .NET or Mono), can potentially give you better performance than Python.

Finally, for close-to-bare-metal performance, C++ is unbeatable, though arguably the most complex of these options, with a significant learning curve. However, most of the example code you'll find online is in C++, which can be an issue if you're not using C++ and aren't comfortable reading it.

Comment: So I downloaded processing and extracted it. I also pasted in some example code from the internet and it is very interesting!!! Can I do other things besides graphics as well, like working with files and user input? Most of the examples that I see online are graphics.

Comment: @MathMan yes, all the features you'd expect are there. See http://www.learningprocessing.com/examples/chapter-18/example-18-1/ and http://processing.org/reference/open_.html. The processing.org site has a ton of documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Qt](http://qt.digia.com/) you can create `QImage` objects and draw on them usign `QPainter`.

You've of course pixel control using that abstraction level, but you can also access the underlying memory directly using `bits()` and `bytesPerLine()` methods thus accessing the image memory directly.

The format that is easiest to use to do fast special computations is in my opinion `QImage::Format_ARGB32` with 32 bits per pixel.

Qt is a C++ library portable on may OSs and platforms, and bindings are available for many very high level languages (e.g. Python).

Comment: I'm not an experienced programmer so I am not sure what you mean by the format "QImage::Format_ARGB32"

Comment: @MathMan: It's an image format where for each pixel you have 4 bytes; 0-255 for red, green and blue and alpha (opacity). All (x, y) pixels are in memory in sequence starting from (0, 0), (1, 0), ..., (w-1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), ..., (w-1, 1), ..., (w-1, h-1).